# How to implement Google API in my Website

Tags: java

[enter link description here http://www.sevenieslab.com.](http://www.sevenieslab.com.)

how can i add google API to allow my user to signup through their gmail account in my website

Comment: You add Oauth2 to your website.

Comment: May I suggest you read Google's documentation on the subject?

Answer (score 1):

For Web applications you can use the Goole Sign-In api.

This sample code can help you get started.
It will return basic user details like : name, profile picture, etc.
You can find more details here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly         to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this information,keep answering...